Why does the opposing team get a point when we tie?
Sometimes, when I’m playing Trackmania 2020 ranked, and both teams tie, the opposing team will always get the point. It’s never my team.
Why is this?

According to the trackmania docs:

in case of a draw in points, the team with the best time in the round wins.

This is only the case if someone has disconnected from the game, so it stands to reason that ties that happen because someone DNFs are still counted as normal ties with no point awarded.
